# Replace static array of objects with GraphQL queried data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I have static data in my React app in a file called `tags.js` as follows:

```
const tagsArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: "test1" 
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: "test2"
  }]
```

I import this into my `index.js` file and use it in my App.

```
import tagsArray from "./tags";

ReactDOM.render(
<App data={tagsArray} />
document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I have a remote GraphQL service containing updated data and want to use a query to pull the array of objects and replace the static `tagsArray`.

I can successfully query the GraphQL data with this function:

```
function GQLTagFunc() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GQLTAGS);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  return data.tag.map(({ id, label }) => (
    <div key={id}>
      id:{id}, label:{label}
    </div>
  ));
}
```

Which returns:

```
id:1, label:"test1"
id:2, label:"test2"
```

I know this format is incorrect but I'm not sure how to modify the function to map the data to the same format (array of objects) as `tagsArray` and then assign it to a variable called `queriedTagsArray` so I could use it in my app as follows:

`<App data={queriedTagsArray} />`

Comment: ?? `data.tag` already is in desired format - check network/json response if in doubt - `<App data={data.tag} />` ?

Comment: @xadm How do I access `data.tag` please as currently this  would error with `'data' is not defined`

Comment: only if not loaded yet? ... use conditions as above (`if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;`) or `if(data) return <App...`

Comment: noooooo, in `GQLTagFunc` you should `return <App...` instead of return `data.tag.map` ... and `<GQLTagFunc/>` inside Apollo provider (instead of App) .... but to be truth you should rename it (index reactDOM.render only 'new' App... App renders Apollo with GQLTagFunc inside ... GQLTagFunc returns WrappedApp (renamed App) after reading data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap entire, existing App into Apollo provider and your querying component.

To keep naming conventions:

- rename your existing `App` to `WrappedApp`,
- create a new `<App/>` component with Apollo initialization and rendering `ApolloProvider' and your query component (`  ` ),
- in `index.js` just `ReactDOM.render( <App/>, document.getElementById("root") );`

Use new name of App (WrappedApp) in `GQLTagFunc`:

```
function GQLTagFunc() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GQLTAGS);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  return <WrappedApp data={data.tag} />;
}
```

### Hint

If this is your only graphql querying then you don't need [big] Apollo at all - you can use fetch/axios to read json data.